# could not show tooltip on mouse over , jquery1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My requirement is to show tooltip on the image mouse over. I'm using jquery1.11 . But I'm not able to achieve it. 
This is **[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubKtd/1129/)**

I want to show below table data on the tooltip on mouseover of the image:

```
<table class="statusRollup" style="position:absolute;">
    <tr><td>tooltip Data1 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>tooltip Data2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Sample code:

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('.one').attr('title', $('.statusRollup').remove().html())
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Are they any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it working, you just need to apply a `title=""` attribute to the items you want to have a tooltip.

```
<td class="sample-two">Row1 
<img class="one" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" 
width="15" height="15" alt="" title="testing"/>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubKtd/1132/

row1's img says testing.

***Also*** I suggest visiting: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

If you want what you asked in the comments here:

JS:

```
$(function () {
      $(document).tooltip({
          content: function () {
              return $(this).prop('title');
          }
      });
  });

$(function () {
    $('.one').attr('title', $('.statusRollup').remove().html())
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Also added jQuery UI as it wasn't added from what I was seeing:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/3/  *** Using jQuery 1.11.1 ***

Comment: My requirement is to show entire table inside tooltip and i cannot add that code in title as suggested. @Simply Craig

Comment: @user3684675 Updated, and added what you asked in comments.

Comment: @user3684675 added jquery1.11 + //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js + //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: I should use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js. Will that be able to give the result ? @  Simply Craig

Comment: @user3684675 I modified my JSFiddle at the bottom to use jquery 1.11  So yes you will be able to.

Comment: @user3684675 updated JSFiddle at bottom (Now it uses exactly your version 1.11.1)  It works like a charm. Please accept the answer so others know this is resolved for you.  Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks it worked, one small question ,can we give event on tooltip. i.e., i want to click on 'tooltip Data1' which should redirect me to some other page, is that possible? @ Simply Craig

Comment: @user3684675 I am sure you can do it.  I am not sure how you would go about that.  I'd recommend going through http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: @user3684675 I would add that it's difficult to see what's going on when you dynamically add chunks of HTML in an attribute; esp. as you're already using the `content` option. I recall recently answering a related question that you may find helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919565